# Acquiring an operand from an instruction

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, disassembly

Given the following x86 assembly instructions:

```
mov     esi, offset off_A
cmp     esi, offset off_B
```

how would I get the offsets (the second operand) at runtime ? This is the scenario: A program (injected into the process at runtime) replaces the offsets with a few of its own, resulting in:

```
mov     esi, offset off_X
cmp     esi, offset off_Y
```

This program allows plugins to be written and loaded through it but doesn't expose the replacement addresses. So, given the addresses at which the above instructions exist, how do I find offsets X and Y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what this is for, but...

`mov esi, ...` is encoded as `BE` followed by the dword operand. If you've got the address of the `mov` instruction you can simply skip one byte ahead and see the address operand, `off_A`

`cmp esi, ...` is encoded as `81 FE` followed by a dword operand, so here you can skip two bytes to see the operand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking. The offset *is* the address. So that first line of code is moving the address of `off_9F6FBC` to esi.

If you mean how to get the absolute address(in combination with PIC and such) then this can not be known at disassembly time. It is only known at runtime and can change every run

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I've edited the question to include details about the usage scenario. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to encode MOV esi, immediate. Depending about your assembler and compiler, any of them might be used.

If you do it without using assembler mnemonics, as in hex. You could pinpoint the offsets there:

```
db 0xBE; off_X: dd normal_offset
```